# Permanently start the OpenBSD pf Firewall on OS X

Tags: osx, firewall, pf

I use Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 at the desktop OS. As everyone knows, is Apple's Mac OS X built on FreeBSD! I use normal only Debian/GNU/Linux on desktop and OpenBSD on Server and Firewall:

So my question: On Apples Mac OS X each can use OpenBSD's pf Firewall.
But every time I re start the Apple Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 the pf Firewall is switched off.
So every time I reboot, first do I need a "sudo su -" on Terminal and I must start the pf with pfctl -E && pfctl -vvf /etc/pf.conf why is that so?
Where could I start a program permanently on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3?

PS: Mac OS X uses OpenBSD's www.Libressl.org per default and OpenBSD's pf who wants!

Answer (score 0):

OS X's primary init system is `launchd`. This is managed via the `launchctl` utility, and you will find the system's non-GUI related configuration files in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist
```

That `-w` flag will cause "Disabled" state of the job configuration to be persistently overridden. If you would like to revert this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist
```

> As everyone knows, is Apple's Mac OS X built on FreeBSD!

It's built on a lot of things, the good ol' Chimera that it is. Gotta love that BSD POSIX layer and userspace subsystem, especially!

Comment: Thank you very much, now pf starts, but a pfctl-sa shows no rules were loaded. This is to despair. The rules are as usual in /etc/pf.conf But no rules are loaded, why only?